# How can I determine if ActiveSync policy is installed in iOS via Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, activesync

I need to make sure a specific security policy (ActiveSync policy) is installed on an iOS-device in order to "lightly" authorise users of my app. Is this possible?

Any comments or resources describing any of this, would be nice.

Comment: What kind of security policy are you referring to ?

Comment: Instead of checking ActiveSync Policy exists or not, you should use a Configuration Profile. Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by wether that target device is `jailbroken` or not. Generally you can check it by check `Cydia.app` is it inside application.

```
NSString *filePath = @"/Applications/Cydia.app";
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
{
    // do something useful
}
```

Another possible outcome is, your app gets cracked. 
[Here](http://thwart-ipa-cracks.blogspot.in/2008/11/detection.html)  is one of the ways to detect if your app was cracked.

Comment: @Viral really? you can't use `fileExistsAtPath` in `/Applications` folder. It's out of App's sandbox access.